# Software to easily organize IE 8 favourites

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have about a hundred links to sort into various folders in Internet Explorer 8 but dragging and dropping each one is time-consuming and is bad for my RSI.

Is there a way to select links not in folders and place them in the appropriate folder in the most efficient way?

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate your Favorites in `c:\users\<your user name>\favorites` via Windows Explorer, which will allow you to select sequential sets (click first one, <kbd>shift</kbd>-click last one) or single, non-sequential items (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click each one you want to add to the selection).  You can also use these in combination with dragging a selection square around items.

You can use these, and combinations of these, to select all the items you want and then drag-n-drop them into a target folder at the same time.

Since you're in a regular Explorer window, you also have all your various display and sort options available to make your filing task easier.

Comment: I'm gonna try it.

Comment: To open Favorites folder, you can shift-click "Organize Favorites..." on the IE "Favorites" menu. Ref: [Organize Favorites by Opening as a Folder](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/ie/orgfav.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few IE Favorites management programs such as [this one](http://download.cnet.com/windows/bookmark-managers/) at CNET.

The programs I've found that print URL lists currently appear to be paid apps.